# Запрет на ввод первым символом пробел

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно запретить вводить пробел первым символом, а дальше уже действовать по такому условию `/[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]/`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как запретить ввод пробела первым символом?

Comment: `^[^\s][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]*$` — как-то так

Comment: Так не работает пробел вовсе

Comment: Так запрещает ввод только пробелов, все остальные символы вводятся(

Comment: Срабатывает только эта часть [^\s]

Comment: Не должно такого быть, показывайте как используете

Comment: /^[^\s][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]*$/.test(event.key)

Comment: Ах, ну конечно, вы проверяете только нажатую клавишу, а не всю уже введенную строку

Comment: Спасибо, ошибку понял

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте такое регулярное выражение:

```
^[^\s][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]*$
```

Здесь:

```
^ — начало строки
[^\s] — любой непробельный символ (ровно один раз)
[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]* — любой символ из вашего набора (любое количество раз)
$ — конец строки
```

<sub>или может `^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]*$`? или даже `^(|[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]*)$`, если нужно считать пустую строку валидным значением</sub>

```js
let box = document.getElementById('box');
let prevVal = "";

box.addEventListener('beforeinput', (e) => { 
  prevVal = box.value;
});

box.addEventListener('input', (e) => { 
  if (!/^(|[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\s]*)$/.test(box.value)) {
    box.value = prevVal;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="box" />
```

<sub>за нормальность кода не отвечаю — первый раз пишу на JS :)</sub>